# Get filesname through javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get list of filenames from a specified folder through javascript?

Comment: In the server or in the browser?

Comment: What environment are you in? A browser, Node.js? Can you show some code?

Comment: I want to access my server folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder you're talking about is on the client, then you can't. It'd bring up all sorts of security issues if JavaScript had that power.

If the folder is on the server then you could use some form of AJAX, with the server side code fetching the files in the specified directory and returning it back to the client.